# Long title in New Stack Overflow Feature dialog obscures close button

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design, popups

All Stack Overflow sites have an orange 'New' button next to the site logo in their top bar if there are new features to be discovered. If the title is too long, the close button (X) is hardly visible, as can be seen right now on the [Russian Stack Overflow site](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/):

[image]